# if user inters invalid input, program should not crash and promt user again - refactoring cli project

Tags: ruby, api, command-line-interface

Built a starwars api using SWAPI.  I want to factor my code so that the following are met:

-At any point in your program, if the user enters invalid input, the program should not crash and prompt the user to try again

-The program shouldn't exit at any time unless the user has explicitly chosen to exit

```
    def menu
    puts "Please select from a category below:" 
    StarwarsCLI::Category.all.each_with_index {|cat, i|

        puts "#{i + 1}. #{cat.name.capitalize} "

    }
    input = gets.chomp.to_i 
    category = StarwarsCLI::Category.all[input-1]
    StarwarsCLI::APIService.get_items(category)
    items = Module.const_get("StarwarsCLI::#{category.name.capitalize}").all

    if (input-1) == 0
        return list_people

    elsif (input-1) == 1
        return list_planets

    elsif (input-1) == 2
        return list_films

    elsif (input-1) == 3
        return list_species

    elsif (input-1) == 4
        return list_vehicles

    elsif (input-1) == 5
        return list_starships

    elsif input == "exit"
        exit 

    else
        puts "Not a valid option, choose another."
        return menu 
    end
end
```

After adding the lines

```
elsif input == "exit"
        exit 

    else
        puts "Not a valid option, choose another."
        return menu
```

my code no longer runs and my error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from bin/starwars:5:in `<main>'
    2: from /mnt/c/Users/skywalker/dev/flatiron/projects/StarwarsCLI/lib/star_wars/command_line_interface.rb:9:in `run'
    1: from /mnt/c/Users/skywalker/dev/flatiron/projects/StarwarsCLI/lib/star_wars/command_line_interface.rb:21:in `menu'
/mnt/c/Users/skywalker/dev/flatiron/projects/StarwarsCLI/lib/star_wars/api_manager.rb:17:in `get_items': undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I could really use some help getting this code to run if anyone would mind explaining exactly whats wrong.

I tried to add a `break if input == "exit"' under line 17 and an error "invalid break" appeared so i though it could add it to the bottom instead

```
https://github.com/codyalvarez/starwars-api
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use begin-rescue to prevent it from crashing first of all.

Comment: The issue is happening in your `get_items` method — you're passing a `nil` `cat`

Comment: Time to learn about the `case` statement, or even better, a Hash look-up table that maps menu options to methods.

Comment: @eightbithero : `input` contains an `Integer`. You can't compare an integer to a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts with

```
input = gets.chomp.to_i
```

You convert the text being entered to an Integer. If the user enters 'exit', the `to_i` method will translate it to 0. After this, you do the comparision based in `(input-1)`. Hence the *exit*-input will be -1. As the last comparision, you ask whether `-1 == 'exit'`, and of course this is an exception.

If you want to keep this IMO weird way to process the user input, you have to check for `-1` to find out, whether the user entered a non-integer value. Of course, this means that your program will also exit, if the user enters something like *Hello Aunt Melanie!*.

Comment: i appreciate this response - Im using the weird way to process the user input because in the starwars series the films are from 1-6 (excluding all the newer disney ones) not 0 - 6. Its strange - inputing a letter returns the disired " puts "Not a valid option, choose another."
        return menu  -- but  when i input a number i get the same error, and when i input "exit" instead of exiting the program it returns, again  puts "Not a valid option, choose another."
        return menu

Comment: Well, this does not mean that you have to process the input in this way, but of course you can do, if you want.